# QEMU built-in smb server problem with winXP guest

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, qemu

After upgrading: When trying to connect a qemu smb share from a windows XP host, I get the following error:

> No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept.

I'm using the following parameter to qemu-system-x86_64 :

```
-net user,net=192.168.0.0/24,smb=/home/tokr/vm/share
```

In the guest I'm trying to map: `\\192.168.0.4\qemu`
I'm guessing the default for connecting to SMB has changed to something not supported by windows XP, but I can't find any way to configure the built-in SMB server.

**Update:**
Adding `min protocol = NT1` to the `[global]` section of the `smb.conf` fixes the connection issue.
But how can I change the QEMU automatically generated `smb.conf` file ?

**Update 2:**
You can't. It is hardcoded in QEMU, - ugly scripting required.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put [SOLVED] [Work-Around]etc. in the question title. After the waiting time click on the gray check mark ✔ and turn it green ✅. This will accept your answer as correct and help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty, but does work.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 ...  -net user,net=192.168.0.0/24,smb=/home/tokr/vm/share ... &

#Fix smb.conf file
sleep 2
sed -e 's/\[qemu\]/min protocol = NT1\n\[share\]/' -i /tmp/qemu-smb.*/smb.conf
```

Comment: Started having the same issue after upgrading `qemu-system*` from **3.1** to **5.2** (Debian 10 to 11). Thanks for the workaround, it works!